# Wireless network not working on some computers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet-connection

I have a wireless router and I configured it to use WPA-PSK.
The issue I have is that the wireless only works on my laptop. My roommate and another friend tried connecting to the network, they managed to connect to it but they have no internet access from it (on my laptop I have internet access).

Do you have any clue about what the issue might be, I didn't change anything else in the setting except WPA-PSK. Also if they connect to it using an UTP cable they have internet access, so the issue is only with the wireless network.

Answer (score 1):

One common cause of this is that the encryption type for the non-working wireless connections is not right - have a look at the properties of the wireless settings and check whether the encryption type is set to TKIP or AES and compare with the working machine, or just try changing the setting.

Answer (score 1):

Is MAC address filtering enabled on the router?